# Dividing two counts with a cast SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a count that I am dividing to get a percent for each month based on a date range. The problem I am having is that the way I have coded it it gives me the percent for the entire date range I put in. So for example every month would be 54 percent instead of a unique percent for each month. I'm sure there is an easy solution I just don't know what it is. I think I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, finspectdata), 0) AS 'Date' 
,COUNT(*) AS Lots
,sum(flotSize) as 'Lot Size'
,sum(fnumreject) as Rejected
,sum(fsampSize) as 'Sample Size'
,((select cast(count(*) as decimal) 
from monthlyinspect 
where finspectData < fddue_date 
and fddue_date >= '20140101' 
and fddue_date <= '20140531') / (select cast(count(*) as decimal) 
from monthlyinspect 
where fddue_date > '20140101' 
and fddue_date < '20140531')) 
FROM monthlyinspect 
WHERE finspectdata >= '20140101' 
AND finspectdata <= '20140531' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, finspectdata), 0)
Order by 'Date'
```

The output is

```
Date                       Lots  Lot Size  Rejected Sample Size   Percent
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000      916    455358  3082    10835   0.5488603615404768142
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000      692    410567  1114    7870    0.5488603615404768142
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000      694    424251  391     8095    0.5488603615404768142
2014-04-01 00:00:00.000      872    429746  1642    10017   0.5488603615404768142
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000      633    312913  572     7340    0.5488603615404768142
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the query then I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT 
      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, finspectdata), 0) AS 'Date' 
    , COUNT(*) AS Lots
    , SUM(flotSize) as 'Lot Size'
    , SUM(fnumreject) as Rejected
    , SUM(fsampSize) as 'Sample Size'
    , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN finspectdata < fddue_date  
                AND 
                    fddue_date >= '20140101'
                AND 
                    fddue_date <= '20140531'
            THEN 
                1
            ELSE 
                0
          END)
          /
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN 
                fddue_date >= '20140101'
                AND 
                    fddue_date <= '20140531'
            THEN 
                1
            ELSE 
                0
          END)      

FROM 
    monthlyinspect 
WHERE 
    finspectdata >= '20140101' 
    AND 
        finspectdata <= '20140531' 
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, finspectdata), 0)
ORDER BY 
    'Date'
```

Hopefully this will put you in the right direction.

Alternatively I would probably look at building this query in a number of steps.

Get the group data in one dataset and then get the percentage in another dataset. then combine the two based on the date.

With something like this I would usually use a temp table (variable) to house the data while I am working on it.

Comment: The percent just came up zero.

Comment: What if you split out the division section and just return the two components as separate fields in you result set just to see what is being thrown back.

Comment: I ended up adding a temporary table to store my numbers and did my calculations from there.

Comment: I find with queries like this it is probably best to break it into smaller chunks and combine the results together. Without any data to test this with it was difficult to give you a complete solution. But glad you got it working in the end.